# Error configuring wildfly as a windows service

Tags: windows, service, wildfly, wildfly-10

I am using wildfly 10.1 in standalone mode and need to use it as a service.
I copied the service files to the bin folder and then installed the service from the command prompt.
This works well, except that it is impossible to stop the service without killing the process using `taskkill`.
As a fix, I tried replacing

```
set DESCRIPTION="WildFly Application Server"
```

with

```
set DESCRIPTION=WildFly Application Server
```

in the service.bat file as mentioned [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-1719). But this is causing the service not to start. The system log says:

> The Wildfly service terminated with the following service-specific
> error:  Incorrect function.

How can I fix this issue and get the service starting and stoppping normally?

Comment: I've the same problem. Did you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

Add System variable `JAVA_HOME` to System variable and try to start the service. It worked for me.